# How to put two variables into one ggplot

Tags: r

Dataset: data

| Region | Forest | Lakes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | 30 | 40 |
| West | 40 | 100 |
| South | 12 | 30 |
| Central | 44 | 200 |

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = Forest)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Lakes)  + ggtitle("Lakes and Forest in different Regions")
```

Unfortunately this is not the right thing.

I would like to show for each region how much lakes and forests they have and then the nearest region in x-axis. How does it work?

Comment: Reshape to long i.e. `data %>% pivot_longer(cols = Forest:Lakes) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_col()`

Comment: But this code show Lakes and Forest in one bar. I would like to have two bars, one for lakes and one for forest. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: You may need position='dodge' i.e. `data %>% pivot_longer(cols = Forest:Lakes) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')`

Comment: updated the comment

Comment: `data %>% pivot_longer(cols = Forest:Lakes) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')` does gives that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then use `geom_col` with `position='dodge'`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Forest:Lakes) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')  + 
  ggtitle("Lakes and Forest in different Regions")
```